# Using apply with spatial data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial

despite best efforts could not find any answer around. I cannot convert the data to data table as I need its spatial attributes for the formula.

How do you use apply per row with spatial data frames?
I have to find the closest match for every item for sp1 from sp2 but still on the same street (what means it might be not absolute closest item geographically). 
a convenient solution without planar projection is `dist2line`
I have to preselect from sp2 items that are on the same street, so effectively I need something of a type

```
sp1$x <- dist2line(sp1, sp2[sp2$street == sp1$street,]) [4]
```

especially that the function will slow down if checking against all sp2. This function will return a matrix with 4 columns with index of the subset `sp2[sp2$street == sp1$street,]` only, not entire sp2 - that's another pitfall - how to get a value from the subset sp2 afterwards?

`dist2line` requires spatial coordinates from both data sets, so it cannot be converted to data table (in dt this operation would be easy). I would like to avoid any iterative method with stepping record by record. Any ideas?

Sorry for not enclosing any reproducible samples - `dput()` does not work effectively with spatial lines data frame and the sp2 are polylines (instead of actual data it returns `<S4 object of class structure("Lines", package = "sp")>` ) and `dist2line` requires lines.

Comment: could you please post a small reproducible sample of your data ?

Comment: Mouad, i would love to but Spatial Lines Data Frame without the lines below is meaningless. Dput() works well with normal tables or SpatialPoints, but not any Lines/Polygons. It is more how to apply any function on spatial table that does not have byid attribute

Comment: At least guide through on how to produce the data ourselves?

Comment: I understand, I was referring to the data component of the object, which could be accessed by the slot operator ie : `spatialObject@data`, in any case , I would explore the rgeos package, get a distance matrix for each of the geometries, then use your condition and the `min()` function, I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. It would not work as a distance matrix would create absolute matrix, not subsetting the sp2 by street. The problem is that sp2 on other streets are sometimes closer. I would need to create a distance matrix for every street, what would make it very close to interation. I resolved the problem by iteration, but for future reference wanted to find a method that would work (and data component is irrelevant for the calculation apart from subsetting the other sp)

Comment: since spatial*objects are lists you could `lapply()`